# C# MySql проблема с зависимыми комбобоксами(combobox)

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Доброе время суток господа, я по видео из youtube вот ссылка на видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0J_VH6Rh4A, сделал зависимость комбобоксов(combobox) как на видео. Суть в том что отображаемые данные второго комбобокса(combobox) зависели от первого, (пример:при выборе района должны отображаться свободные машины находящиеся в этом районе) но результата нет. подскажите варианты как реализовать?

вот код C# :

```
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace check2
{
public partial class check2 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;initial catalog=test;username=root;password=");
    MySqlCommand cmnd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapt;
    DataTable tbl;


    public check2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void check2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT `id_loc`, `locations` FROM `local`";
        fillcmbo(comboBox1, query, "location", "id_loc");
        comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null);
    }

    public void fillcmbo(ComboBox combo, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        cmnd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
        adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmnd);
        tbl = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(tbl);
        combo.DataSource = tbl;
        combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int val;
        Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
        string query = "SELECT `id_car`, `id_status`, `id_location` FROM `car_stat_loc` WHERE `id_location`=" +val;
        fillcmbo(comboBox2, query, "location", "id_loc");
    }
 }
}
```

вот скриншот ошибки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQyss.jpg

Comment: А какого результата? У вас первый комбобокс отображает список городов?

Comment: Город опечатка, при выборе района должны отображаться машины с статусами равны 1(то есть свободным). результат должен быть таков!

Comment: Проверяйте свои параметры: в первом вызове `locations` и `location`. Во втором, вместо `location` и `id_loc`, вероятно, должны быть `id_location` и `id_car` или `id_status`.

Comment: тут на combo.ValueMember = valueMember; выдаёт ошибку при запуске приложении

Comment: Какую ошибку? Приведите **всю** релевантную информацию.

Comment: оно просить заполнить нулы в comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null); поскольку данные для других есть но к ValueMember = valueMember; нету, я не понял почему так!